# Fortran subroutine returning None in python c.f. working in R

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

Im trying to implement some probability work that utilises the bivariate normal cdf. In R I can use [the pbivnorm package](https://github.com/brentonk/pbivnorm) (line [90](https://github.com/brentonk/pbivnorm/blob/master/R/pbivnorm.r#L90) specifically), e.g. (with some made up numbers)

```
library(pbivnorm)
.Fortran("PBIVNORM", as.double(0), c(0,0), as.double(-0.1), as.double(-0.2), as.integer(c(0,0)), as.double(0), as.integer(1), PACKAGE="pbivnorm")

[[1]]
[1] 0.193613

[[2]]
[1] 0 0

[[3]]
[1] -0.1

[[4]]
[1] -0.2

[[5]]
[1] 0 0

[[6]]
[1] 0

[[7]]
[1] 1
```

I've taken the underlying Fortran code from [the package here](https://github.com/brentonk/pbivnorm/blob/master/src/pbivnorm.f) and compiled it using F2py (named the compiled .so file fortran) so I can e.g. do:

```
import fortran
fortran.pbivnorm(float(0), [float(0), float(0)], float(-0.1), float(-0.2), [int(0), int(0)], float(0),int(1))
```

however this returns None. I know that the subroutine technically is changing the values supplied to it so I also supplied various named constants but they remain unchanged when queried.

Also feel like maybe could be to do with fussiness over input types?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right with an assumption that there is a mismatch with the types. Default python types (lists) are not ok for calling this function. Also the variable `PROB` is used as the output for this function, so you can not just use a literal for it. By looking at the original fortran function signature, your arguments and code should look like this:

```
import fortran
import numpy as np


PROB = np.array([0], order="F", dtype=np.double)
LOWER = np.array([0, 0], order="F", dtype=np.double)
UPPERA = np.array([-0.1], order="F", dtype=np.double)
UPPERB = np.array([-0.2], order="F", dtype=np.double)
INFIN = np.array([0, 0], order="F", dtype=np.int32)
CORREL = np.array([0], order="F", dtype=np.double)
LENGTH = np.int32(1)

fortran.pbivnorm(PROB, LOWER, UPPERA, UPPERB, INFIN, CORREL, LENGTH)

print(PROB, LOWER, UPPERA, UPPERB, INFIN, CORREL, LENGTH)
```

Comment: cheers! thought it might be something like that but wasnt sure how to implement the parameters :D

Out of interest, is R doing something under the hood to pass vectors into the called Fortran that the base types can slot right in? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: (will award bounty once the time limit expires)

Comment: Hello. I am not acquainted with R language, but I think it just somehow implicitly converts the built-in R types to the suitable types for Fortran. The mechanism for calling functions from compiled libraries is common. In Python you also may use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to call functions directly from a library, but this requires extra knowledge